# horizontal lines and color flashing to top of screen in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: screen, acer

I having some problem on my laptop screen of Acer predator helios 300 since today. I am using ubuntu 22.04 since 5 months. This morning i opened my laptop and seen that my screen is splitted into n small horizontal lines and also colors of some non black icon, text or button goes all the way up as shown in the picture.
[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]

the weird part is that when i took screenshot of the screen and view screenshot on my other monitor its completely fine.

please help me.

Comment: Is the issue present in BIOS screen? Also, try booting a live USB. If the issue is there in the BIOS screen or the live session, it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: issue persist with try ubuntu using pendrive

Comment: And what about BIOS screen?

Comment: this was the hardware issue . I have to replace the screen

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a hardware issue.